# interior and adherence

Tags: general-topology

i have a difficulties for this question. Can you help me please to resolve it.
For all $r \in \mathbb{R}_+,$ we let $$\Omega_r = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, x= r \cos t , y = r \sin t , t \in [0,2 \pi]\}$$ and we consider the family $\sigma = \{\Omega_r , r \in \mathbb{R}_+\}$ 
We endow $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the topology $\tau$ such as its base is $\sigma.$ Let $$A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |x+y| > 2\}$$

My question is: can you give me please an simple methode to find $\overline{A}$ and the interior of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

The basis elements of this topology are the circles centered at $(0, 0)$. Here is what the region $A$ looks like:

[image: Region A]

The interior of $A$ consists of all open sets contained in $A$. Which basis elements are in $A$? The answer is none, and therefore the interior is empty.

$\overline{A}$ consists of $A$ and its limit points. $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ intersects with $A$ at a point other than $x$ itself. Can you identify all such points? Which basis elements intersect with $A$?

Comment: Let $x \in A.$ Any voisinage of $x$ must contain an circle $\Omega_r$ but i don't know how we find all the point $x$ such that $\forall V \in \mathcal{V}(x), V \cap A \neq {x}$ Can you help me please on this difficuties.

Comment: @luluuuu Which circles $\Omega_r$ from $\sigma$ intersect with $A$?